# How to put an android layout's element over another one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have the following problem: I want to put a CardView over another one in an android layout file.
So in android studio layout editor the result is this and it's what I want:
the cardView round one top right of the rectangular CardView, at the same elevation

[image: What I want]

But if I start the emulator the result is this:

[image: the result I get]

This is the code of the two cardView:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dati1h"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="483dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dati1h"
        android:layout_marginBottom="480dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_foreground"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I really don't know how to solve it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

how about make RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/dati1h"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dati1h"
        android:layout_marginBottom="480dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_foreground"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an issue with the code as you declared `info` CardView after `dati1h` that means info cardView should get rendered over dati1h. But this can be a device specific issue i have faced similar issue before (For constraint layout).

To solve it i chose to increase the elevation which will solve it for sure.

But as you don't want to follow that approach try using Frame/Relative Layout as parent of both CardView(instead of constraint layout) and it should solve your issue.